# Beautiful Soup not parsing all tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table, html-parsing

I have attached a screenshot of the HTML of the website I am trying to scrape, there is a table and within it I want to get some of the data from the rows which are within body (they clearly exist), however, it was not working so I decided to print tbody which revealed that the parsing found the table and tbody but not the rows within. I don't know how to fix this any help would be appreciated.[HTML from wesbite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF9e5.png)

[Output when printing body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H2RK.png)

This is the beginning of my code:

```
url = "https://superfpl.com/player_stats"

results = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

players = []

teams = []

positions = []

ownerships = []

print(soup.find("tbody"))

player_div = soup.find_all('tr', role_="row",  class_="odd")
```

Comment: The table is empty in the HTML. It's later filled in by JavaScript.

Comment: Duplicate of [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically through JavaScript. But you can simulate it with the `requests` module:

```
import requests

url = 'https://superfpl.com/ajax/player_stats'
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to see all data (WARNING, huge list!):
# import json
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# pretty print some data to screen:
for row in data['data']:
    print('{:<20}{:<20}{:<20}'.format(row['web_name'], row['position'], row['points_per_game']))
```

Prints:

```
Connolly            FWD                 2.4                 
Cresswell           DEF                 2.7                 
Lennon              MID                 0.9                 
Mooy                MID                 2.9                 
Ramsdale            GKP                 3.4                 
Wan-Bissaka         DEF                 3.3                 
Koiki               DEF                 0.0                 
Doucouré            MID                 3.3                 
Idah                FWD                 1.3                 
Lallana             MID                 1.8                 
Masina              DEF                 2.8                 
Adam Smith          DEF                 2.2                 

... and so on.
```

Comment: I was just wondering where you got that link as I can't find it on the normal website

Comment: @RubenVarghese If you open Network Tab in Firefox developer tools (Chrome has something similar too..) you will see it - it's the link with biggest Transferred size (has over 34MB)